# dylon material dyed wood and watco oil and wax finish on oak

Tags: furniture, refinishing, coloring

I have stripped down a 60s oak dinning table and chairs with paint stripper, then washed with TPS as per paint remover instructions. I then dyed the wood with Dylon material dye "deep blue".

The finish color turned out different than I had planned because (I believe) there was some oak stain still in the wood.  It turned out to be a very dark (almost black) finish with a hint of blue, which I thought was very nice.

I wanted a very natural soft look so I then used Watco natural oil - 2 coats as per can instructions. I waited a day but the blue dye still could be wiped off. I thought the oil would be a hard seal finish, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So then I tried to top the finish with Watco wax finish as per can instructions. However, I can still wipe blue dye of the table.  When the table is dry and you run your hand or dry cloth over it the dye does not seem to come off.  However, if you use a damp dish cloth it comes off like there is no finish on it at all.

So now I have taken the two leaves and washed them with TPS as per "taking wax off" instructions.  With this procedure I am loosing a lot of my dark color but I will be okay with the lighter color.  I am waiting a day.  (The temperature is very warm here; it is about 25 degrees c. outside.)

Now I want to know what product I can use to lock in the color.  This product will have to be compatible with the danish oil.  Should I use something like Varathane?  I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: First off a general thing about staining wood with a dye stain is that you flood the surface *and then wipe the surface dry*. This removes all the excess. I presume you didn't do that given the extremely dark colour you achieved initially? Anyway you need what's called a film finish to lock in the colour — shellac, varnish (includes polyurethane), waterbased finish or lacquer. Because it's famous for sticking well to virtually everything shellac is what I would want to try first, but it may be difficult for you to get the lightest (bleached) shades of it which are the least yellow.